# Set input value into kendo template

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-template

I pass json into kendo template from ajax, and next i need set value of my inputs in template. I'm trying this:

```
                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Service/MyService.svc/GetTestObjects",
                        data: '{"objectID": ' + '"' + myVal + '"}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        processdata: true,
                        success: function (msg) {

                            var template = kendo.template($("#myTemplate").html());
                            var templateView = template(msg.GetTestObjects);

                            $("#myContainer").html(templateView);
                        },
                        error: function (msg) {
                            console.log(msg)
                        }
                    });

<input id="myInput" class="form-control" value=#= data.Text_Value# />
```

and if property contains more than one word, template set only first ... for example if Text_Value = "test value" ... inputs value is only "test" ...

i tried print in console object data from template and it's OK. So I dont have idea what is wrong with it.

Can anyone help me fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encase it in "" marks like this:

```
<input id="myInput" class="form-control" value="#= data.Text_Value#" />
```

Because your code is generating invalid HTML like:

```
<input id="myInput" class="form-control" value=test value />
```